# Javascript Address Bar Hack/Trick

Tags: javascript

We've all seen this:

`javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true'; document.designMode='on'; void 0`

But my question is, how does this actually work, surely if this code isnt in the source code, how does it have any effect when entered into the address bar?

Comment: How is this not a real question!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `javascript: <anything>` as a link or into the address bar will basically run the given piece of JS.

Instead of onclick or onmouseover you can just put `<a href="javascript:alert('hi')">Test</a>` if you really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The `javascript:` prefix instructs the browser to execute a script, rather than follow a link.

You probably know that you can alert a message like this:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('test');">Click me</a>
```

Now, entering `javascript:alert('test');` in the address bar of the browser is the exact same thing as following that link. Hence the code will be executed. It's a feature =)

Answer (score 0):

It is a HTML5 specification and can be applied in the page itself or via adressbar like every javascript code... like a javascript bookmarklet from twitter.

Reference:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable